# How to Define a Recursive Function with 2 Arguments in Python

Tags: python, function, recursion

I mean to define the following recursive function

[recursive formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbR5e.png)

But I don't know what goes wrong in my code. May anyone more experienced with Python take a look into that? Thank you!

```py
    import scipy.special

def F(n,k):
    if (k == 1):
        F = 1
    else:
        F = 0
        j = 1
        while (j <= n-k+1):
            a = scipy.special.binom(n,j)
            b =  F(n-j,k-1)
            F = F + a*b
            j = j + 1
    return F
```

Comment: please fix formatting so this is legible

Comment: @DetectivePikachu For some reason, Stack Overflow doesn't support LaTeX, even though other Stack Exchange communities such as [mathematics.se] does. I added a rendered image of the equation.

Comment: It would help if you would give an input for which the expected output clashes with the output that would come from evaluating the formula by hand.

Comment: The attempted MathJax in your last edit is almost certainly not what you wanted. Please either restore the graphic inserted by John Coleman or correct your MathJax. If you do the latter, one of us can insert the appropriate graphic.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Sorry, I'm not allowed to upload a picture yet, and it seems that I couldn't restore sth. before either. I didn't know there's a picture. I'll see what I can do... sorry

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
import scipy.special

def F(n,k):
    if (k == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return sum(scipy.special.binom(n,j) * F(n-j,k-1) for j in range(1, n-k+2))
```

In your code you are reassigning to F, which you define as function (`def F(n,k)`), the value of an int (`F = 1`). In this way, when the value k is greater than 1 you get this error:

```
b =  F(n-j,k-1)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Because now F is an int, not a function anymore

Comment: This is a cleaner way to write it than OP's way (so +1) -- but it really seems like it is computing the same function. It doesn't explain what, if anything, is actually wrong with OP's code. Minor nit-pick: why the square brackets inside of `sum()`? No real reason to gather the iterable into a list before summing.

Comment: @JohnColeman I updated the answer with the error :) thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks so much, guys! This is very clarifying! (I'm a beginner in Python. I just write whatever comes to my mind first. So sometimes I don't kow what I'm doing ...)

Comment: @Ariel Leung. You are welcome. Please accept the best answer also :). Hope to see you around

Comment: Also, when n takes larger numbers, these codes become rather slow. For example, it takes more than 15 minutes to compute F(1000,500). So I'm thinking ... are there faster way to do a recursive function? A package, perhaps? Or I'm just daydreaming, then ignore me ... sorry. And thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with @ArielLeung's `code` is that it defines both the function `F(n,k)` and the variable returned `F` as `F`. This creates ambiguity in the variable namespace.

The following should work fine.

```py
import scipy.special

def F(n,k):
    f = 0
    if (k == 1):
        f = 1
    else:
        f = 0
        j = 1
        while (j <= n-k+1):
            a = scipy.special.binom(n,j)
            b =  F(n-j,k-1)
            f = f + a*b
            j = j + 1
    return f
```

However, I would prefer @Nikaidoh's list comprehension as a much concise solution.

Comment: Good catch. I had trouble spotting the error (which is obvious in retrospect).

Comment: @ArielLeung Please `accept` the best answer. [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)